# Packages Imports problem in flutter in vs code

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, import, package

I have got some problems when I'm trying to import some packages in flutter in VS code.

**The problem -**
"Target of URI doesn't exist: 'package:http_auth/http_auth.dart'.
Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or Try using a URI for a file that does exist.darturi_does_not_exist"

I tried to update packages in pubspec.yaml, to restart the IDE and even the computer :)
but nothing successed.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

import 'package:http_auth/http_auth.dart';`

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';
```

**and this is the relevant code from pubspec.yaml:**

version: 1.0.0+1
environment:

```
sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"
```

dependencies:

```
flutter:
  sdk: flutter
  paypal: ^0.0.4
  paypal_sdk_flutter: ^0.0.2
  http_auth: ^1.0.0
  shared_prefernces: ^0.2.0
http: ^0.13.3

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
```

Comment: Perhaps you could wrap those in code backticks (or select the entire code and hit ctrl-k). That way we'll be able to see the indentation for your code as well. As you know, yaml files depend on indentation

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to specify what "problems" you are facing.

Comment: thank you i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your imports
import 'package:http/http.dart' should look like below and reference here for proper install [http dart](https://pub.dev/packages/http/install)

```
import 'package:http/http.dart';
```

other packages need to be formatted as this

```
import 'package:package/location';
```

for pubspec.yaml, check your formatting, the lines all need to have proper indents.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you explain please what is the "location" ?

Comment: it is the location of the package.  Either from your local library or in the case of the http, an external library.  An internal location would look like 'package: project/exampleFile';